Fastapi streamlit shared cookie for external token
I submitted another question related to this but I may not be enough clear, so I'd like to widen my question :
I set up two subdomain (https) sf.mydomain.synology.me and sf2.mydomain.synology.me.
First points to streamlit app, second to fastapi app.
In fastapi, I have several routes : login, callback and contacts_count. Login goes to salesforce connected app, allow to select user, authorize access and give back token with callback route. The contacts_count route should request salesforce and count contacts per year and send it back to streamlit. I store token and instance URL in sessionmiddleware
In my streamlit app, I have a link to login and I button to requests contacts_count.
Whereas I can login with streamlit, and requests contacts_count in browser (by https://sf2.mydomain.synology.me/contacts_count, I can see the result), when I request it from streamlit app, it doesn't work indicating "token or instance url empty".
Can someone share bestpractice to securely share data between fastapi and streamlit in two subdomains (note that both runs in the same docker projects with 2 containers)
Thank you
